# Reduce linq query for filtering

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq, entity-framework

I have a view with 3 textboxes which bind to properties in the ViewModel `SupplierName`, `Contact`, `Address` and one button which bind to `SearchCommand` property in my ViewModel.

My requirement is to filter `Supplier` records based on the above properties. I used EntityFramework.

The user can enter any of the above textboxes which lead me to write 9 different queries. 
For instance if the user inputs data only on the `SupplierName` textbox then I need to run one query with `SupplierName` as parameter. If the user enters `SupplierName` and `Contact` textboxes then I need to run another query. And so on.

Here is my code:

```
public IEnumerable<Model.Supplier> GetAllSuppliersBySearch(string nameMatch, string contactMatch, string phoneMatch)
    {

        if(nameMatch!=null)
        {
             var q = from f in Context.Suppliers
                where f.SupplierName==nameMatch 
                select f;
        }
        else if(contactMatch!=null)
        {
             var q = from f in Context.Suppliers
                where  f.ContactName==contactMatch 
                select f;
        }
        else if(phoneMatch!=null)
        {
            var q = from f in Context.Suppliers
                where  f.ContactName==contactMatch 
                select f;
        }

        return q.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

Instead of writing multiple queries, how to accomplish this with one query or in any optimized way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Compose query with lambda syntax:

```
IQueryable<Supplier> query = Context.Suppliers;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nameMatch))
   query = query.Where(s => s.SupplierName == nameMatch);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contactMatch))
   query = query.Where(s => s.ContactName == contactMatch);

// etc

return query.AsEnumerable();
```

Another option is adding parameter-checking conditions to query

```
var query = 
   from s in Context.Suppliers
   where (String.IsNullOrEmpty(nameMatch) || s.SupplierName == nameMatch) &&
         (String.IsNullOrEmpty(contactMatch) || s.ContactName == contactMatch)
         // etc
   select s;
```